# How to get Pandas Dataframe max values by column as well as the id's of the max value per column

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently doing the following on a very large dataset and wondered if there was a way to genearate the df.idxmax and df.max values from one "scan" of the array to achieve a timesaving compared to my current individual calls.

A small example:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 9, 3], [4, 8, 1], [5, 7, 4], [7, 1, 1]],
    ...:                   columns='A B C'.split(), index='T1 T2 T3 T4'.split())

In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
    A  B  C
T1  5  9  3
T2  4  8  1
T3  5  7  4
T4  7  1  1

In [30]: df.idxmax()
Out[30]: 
A    T4
B    T1
C    T3
dtype: object

In [31]: df.max()
Out[31]: 
A    7
B    9
C    4
dtype: int64
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `agg` on `df`

```
df.agg(['max', 'idxmax'])

Out[981]:
         A   B   C
max      7   9   4
idxmax  T4  T1  T3
```